# How to combine multiple querysets in a Django view?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am developing an exam page, where the user can take an exam several times and the results will be saved in the Score model. Currently I can store the results of the logged in user, but I need it to show me the entire list of scores they have achieved when I enter the details of each user.

I have access to the list of users with the userList view, and I can access the details of each user with the userDetail view, but I want to know if there is a way to show all the scores of the selected user in the same details view.

Here's de Score model:
**MODELS**

```
class Score(models.Model):
#The user field is a foreign key from User(AbstractUser)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    evaluation_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

These are the views I'm using for the user list, user detail and saving the new score:
**VIEWS**

```
class userList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = "users/list.html"
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    context_object_name = "users"

class userDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = "users/detail.html"
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    context_object_name = "user"

@csrf_protect
def send(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'answers' in request.POST:
            answers = request.POST['answers']
            time = datetime.datetime.now()
            current_user = request.user
            Note.objects.create(
                user = current_user,
                score = answers,
                evaluation_date = time
            )
            return HttpResponse('Successful')
    return HttpResponse('FAIL!')
```

And these are the URLs from user list and user detail:
**URL**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('list/', userList.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('list/<int:pk>/', userDetail.as_view(), name='detail')
]
```

I tried sending multiple contexts as follows:

```
class userDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    context_object_name = "data"
    template_name = "users/detail.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        myset = {
            "user": User.objects.all(),
            "score": Score.objects.all(),
            .
            .
            .
        }
        return myset
```

But I only got an error with the primary key

```
<int:pk>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a view that has access to `user` object, you can do `user.score_set.all()` to access all the scores for that particular user.
In your `userDetail` view:

```py
class userDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    ... 
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["user_scores"] = self.object.score_set.all()
        return context
```

`user_scores` will thus be available in the user detail template.

**Side note**
Python's best practices say class names in Python should be in PascalCase, not camelCase. So, <strike>`userDetail`</strike> should really be `UserDetail`.

Comment: I get a 'User' object has no attribute 'user_score', I think thats because Django is looking for an especific field un the User model, but the Score is a whole model and the user is just a foreign key. So what I need is get the User and Score model and show only the scores for that user.

Comment: Look closely at the answer, it should be `user.score_set.all()`.

Comment: It's true, I had written it wrong, thanks for your help, it worked!